# Create date from integers in separate fields in athena aws

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm super new to athena, so bear with me. I have data stored as integers in three separate columns for year, month and day, as such:

```
year   month   day
2020   7       10
2020   7       11
2020   7       12
```

I'd like to turn these three fields into one date. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just concatenate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method is:

```
select date_parse(cast(year * 10000 + month * 100 + day as varchar(255)), '%Y%m%d')
```

This should also work:

```
select date(year || '-' || month || '-' || day)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method worked, since I needed to first cast the three fields from integers into one varchar.

Comment: Is it possible to go from an 8-digit integer straight to a date, or must you go through varchar?

Comment: For me the first solution worked but not the second, which returns:


`Unexpected parameters (bigint, varchar(1)) for function concat.`

Comment: Couldn't understand method one even after looking at docs https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions. Why multiply year by 1000 and same for others?

Comment: @akshay… because you need the month and day of month.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `concat()` function. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/concat-function.html).

Depending of the format that you want to use, this can change.

```
concat(year, '-' , month , '-', day)
```